# How to get a dialog to appear automatically when we focus on a bar graph using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, flot

I have a graph like this [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/24/)

Now on plotHover i can see the selection of the bar.How to get a dialog to automatically appear on plotHover or as soon as we focus on it.?

Dialog like this [image: Dialog image]

Comment: What dialog? Regular javascript dialog?

Comment: @WTK i have added the dialog type..See something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use technique from this example (click enable tooltip below the chart to see the tooltip on hover) http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html

If the tooltip is really suppose to look like the one you've pasted it is simple matter of styling with css.

Comment: Its Nice. I have created a div on click of the bar.it gets created.Now i want that div to disappear after sometime.How to do that?

Comment: Kinda' like this http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/27/ (btw - don't use the same id, in your case #tooltip, for more than one element)